# Use populate on a substring of a field with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform, mongoose

I'm in the process of migrating my API from Parse.com to my own Express.js code. I created my mongoose models to match the database created by parse but I am running into an issue concerning the pointers (relations).

Here is two models (simplified as much as possible)

```
const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id           : { type: String, required: true, default: () => randomstring.generate(10) },
  name          : { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  _p_group      : { type: String, required: true, trim: true, set: v => `Group\$${v}`, get: v => v.substr(6) },
});


const GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id           : { type: String, required: true, default: () => randomstring.generate(10) },
  name          : { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
});
```

So here is the issue: `_p_group` is a "pointer" to a `Group`, but parse does not store the id in it, instead it stores `Group$THE_ID`. For example if the customer is from the group who has the id `ndj879gLjt`,`_p_group` will contain `Group$ndj879gLjt`.

How can I handle relations? How can I return a Customer and its group? The usual way is to add `ref: "Group"` into the options of `_p_group` and do a `Customer.find({}).populate('_p_group')`, but for obvious reason it doesn't work here.

Parse is using mongodb (but not mongoose) so there has to be a way, somehow. Also, the solution has to be compatible with Parse. In the worst case I can still create a new field `_customer` that would contains the id, but that would make me update 20Go of data, which is not really what I want.

Answer (score -1):

For populate to work your type should be `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`, so that an `ObjectId` is stored, and property `ref` should be the name of the collection referring to.

I think the following should work with `populate`

```
const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id           : { type: String, required: true, default: () => randomstring.generate(10) },
  name          : { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  _p_group      : { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Group', required: true, trim: true },
});
```

Comment: In a perfect world it would, but `_p_group` is set by Parse and it puts a (special) `String` in it. Changing the type to `ObjectId` would break the compatibility with Parse. I also already have millions of rows in my database, I cannot just change the type that easily.

Comment: ah right. you can pass the `ref` to the populate call i.e.: `Customer.find().populate('_p_group', null, 'Group')`, however that still leaves the problem of the `_id` having `Group$` before it. I'm not sure about the order of execution, but maybe you can bind to `CustomerSchema.post('find', function(r, n){ r = r.map(function(a){ a._id.replace('Group$',''); return a; }; n() });` to process the ids. Not sure if that will get called before populate though, just speculating.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work, the code is called too late. `post` is actually called after the getter set on `_p_group`.

Answer (score -2):

So after looking at the [Parse Server source code](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) it *seems* that they are actually doing several requests, and don't use populate at all. They first gonna find all the `Customers` that match the query, then loop over the result to get a list of groupId, and they query `Group` where `_id in [list of groupId]`.

Comment: Why in hell am I getting a downvote? If that's not how Parse does then explain, otherwise it IS a valid answer. It's not a "nice and clean" answer, but that is still the way it is currently working on Parse, and people might want to know or might want to do the same.